# Svelte - Help to parse data from API - object json

Tags: svelte

I am having issues displaying the data I am fetching from an API.

Sample json data:

```
{
"records": [
    {
        "event": {
            "type": "navigate"
        },
        "setup": {
            "attributes": {
                "title": "New Tab"
            },
            "description": "",
            "name": "",
            "type": null,
            "url": "chrome://newtab/"
        },
        "time": 1612271431271
    },
    {
        "event": {
            "type": "navigate"
        },
        "setup": {
            "url": "https://3.basecamp.com/signup/account/new?plan=one_v1"
        },
        "time": 1612271438035
    },
    {
        "event": {
            "type": "focus"
        },
        "setup": {
            "altPath": "article/form/section[1]/div[1]/input[@id='signup_full_name'][@name='signup[full_name]'][@type='text']",
            "altSelector": "article #signup_full_name",
            "attributes": {
                "autofocus": "autofocus",
                "class": "input session-fields__signup floating-placeholder__input",
                "id": "signup_full_name",
                "name": "signup[full_name]",
                "placeholder": "Your name",
                "rcrdr-extra-style": {
                    "display": "block",
                    "visibility": "visible"
                },
                "required": "required",
                "type": "text"
            },
            "computedRole": "textbox",
            "frame": "0",
            "frame_id": "0",
            "html": "<input class=\"input session-fields__signup floating-placeholder__input\" placeholder=\"Your name\" required=\"required\" autofocus=\"autofocus\" type=\"text\" name=\"signup[full_name]\" id=\"signup_full_name\">",
            "nodeName": "input",
            "nodeType": 1,
            "rootpath": "/html/body/main/div/section/article/form/section[1]/div[1]/input",
            "selector": "#signup_full_name",
            "xpath": "id(\"signup_full_name\")"
        },
        "time": 1612271489789
    }
]
```

}

My goal is to display each key in a table, for example, the output should look like this:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4hGI.png)

What I have tried so far was:

```
<script>
import { onMount } from "svelte";
   // Please, consider the data sample provided above.
  const apiURL =
    "http://localhost/electron/my-test/data.json";
  let recordsObject = [];
  let records;

  onMount(async () => {
    const response = await fetch(apiURL);
    if (response.status === 200) {
      console.log("Success");
      recordsObject = await response.json();
      records = JSON.stringify(recordsObject);
      //   console.log(recordsObject);
      console.log(records);
    } else {
      throw new Error(response.status);
    }
  });

</script>

<section>
  <ul>
    {#each [records] as record}
      <li>
        {record}
      </li>
    {/each}
  </ul>
</section>
```

The output I get is something like this:

```
{"records":[{"event":{"type":"navigate"},"setup":{"attributes":{"title":"New Tab"},"description":"","name":"","type":null,"url":"chrome://newtab/"},"time":1612271431271},{"event":{"type":"navigate"},"setup":{"url":"https://3.basecamp.com/signup/account/new?plan=one_v1"},"time":1612271438035},{"event":{"type":"focus"},"setup":{"altPath":"article/form/section[1]/div[1]/input[@id='signup_full_name'][@name='signup[full_name]'][@type='text']","altSelector":"article #signup_full_name","attributes":{"autofocus":"autofocus","class":"input session-fields__signup floating-placeholder__input","id":"signup_full_name","name":"signup[full_name]","placeholder":"Your name","rcrdr-extra-style":{"display":"block","visibility":"visible"},"required":"required","type":"text"},"computedRole":"textbox","frame":"0","frame_id":"0","html":"<input class=\"input session-fields__signup floating-placeholder__input\" placeholder=\"Your name\" required=\"required\" autofocus=\"autofocus\" type=\"text\" name=\"signup[full_name]\" id=\"signup_full_name\">","nodeName":"input","nodeType":1,"rootpath":"/html/body/main/div/section/article/form/section[1]/div[1]/input","selector":"#signup_full_name","xpath":"id(\"signup_full_name\")"},"time":1612271489789},{"event":{"type":"focus"},"setup":{"altPath":"article/form/section[1]/div[1]/input[@id='signup_full_name'][@name='signup[full_name]'][@type='text']","altSelector":"article #signup_full_name","attributes":{"autofocus":"autofocus","class":"input session-fields__signup floating-placeholder__input","data-sc-fieldtype":"FULL_NAME","data-sc-fieldtype-id":"160","id":"signup_full_name","name":"signup[full_name]","placeholder":"Your name","rcrdr-extra-style":{"display":"block","visibility":"visible"},"required":"required","type":"text"},"computedRole":"textbox","frame":"0","frame_id":"0","html":"<input class=\"input session-fields__signup floating-placeholder__input\" placeholder=\"Your name\" required=\"required\" autofocus=\"autofocus\" type=\"text\" name=\"signup[full_name]\" id=\"signup_full_name\" data-sc-fieldtype=\"FULL_NAME\" data-sc-fieldtype-id=\"160\">","nodeName":"input","nodeType":1,"rootpath":"/html/body/main/div/section/article/form/section[1]/div[1]/input","selector":"#signup_full_name","xpath":"id(\"signup_full_name\")"},"time":1612271498250}
```

Please, is anyone able to help me to display the output in a table using svelte?

Thank you.

## Edit:

I have changed my code:

```
<script>
  const apiURL =
    ...src/Data/data.json";
  let recordsObject = [];
  let records = [];
  let results = {};

  let disabled = false;
  let promise = Promise.resolve([]);

  async function getDataFromApi() {
    const response = await fetch(apiURL);
    recordsObject = await response.json();
    records = recordsObject.records;
    // console.log(records);
    console.log(records.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
      results[i] = records[i];
    }
    console.log(results);
    if (response.status === 200) {
      console.log("Success");
      //   console.log(recordsObject);
    } else {
      throw new Error(response.status);
    }
  }

  function handleClick() {
    promise = getDataFromApi();
    disabled = true;
  }
</script>

<button on:click={handleClick} {disabled}> Load Data </button>

{#await promise}
  <p>retrieving data...</p>
{:then results}
  <li>
    {#each [{ results }] as record}
      {record}
    {/each}
  </li>
{:catch error}
  <p style="color: red">{error.message}</p>
{/await}
```

Now the output is simply:

- [object Object]

Please, do you know why I get this output?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to point out a few things that should help out, and I highly recommend reading the following:

- [Svelte each blocks](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/each-blocks)
- [Svelte await blocks](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/await-blocks)

### records is a string but should be an array

Your variable called `records` is a single string; we can see this on the line stating `records = JSON.stringify(recordsObject);`.

Because it is a string and not an array, you are converting it into an array of one item in your `each` block using `{#each [records] as record}`. Syntactically that works, but that's almost certainly not what you want. What you actually want is for the `records` variable to equal the array **inside of** the json response.

```js
records = recordsObject.records
```

If you are wondering why that works, then I highly recommend reading further on [working with javascript objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

### Tables are not automatic

Each record is a javascript object, essentially a bundle of key-value pairs. Svelte does not automatically convert an object into a table because it does not, and cannot, know how. That's up to you to format using HTML.

So, when you have this in your code:

```js
<li>
  {record}
</li>
```

That's just gonna spit out the raw object. You have to format it into a table yourself. The link on Svelte each blocks I provided earlier gives a small example of how to get started on that task.

For your specific case, the following is a start on how you can decompose a record into its different parts.

```js
<li>
  Type: {record.event.type}; Time: {record.time}
</li>
```

Comment: I made some changes in my code in now I get the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'event' of undefined". `<script>
  
    records = recordsObject.records;

{#await promise}
  <h1>Loading...</h1>
  {#each [{ records }] as { record }}
    <li>
      Type: {record.event.type}; Time: {record.time}
    </li>
  {/each}
{/await}` I don't understand why I get 'event' of undefined. Thanks

Comment: The expression you're using for `each` doesn't work. If `records` is an array, you don't need to wrap it in `[ ]` nor `{ }`. Here's a repl I made showcasing this: https://svelte.dev/repl/b8e71d9c607141c6bf51790f1882a6ee?version=3.40.2

Comment: Hi @Auroratide. Thank you and finally, I managed to get the data. Your inputs were decisive for that. [REPL] 
 (https://svelte.dev/repl/e02d14a39108432ab534f7527a2e441b?version=3.40.2) Now i will see how to format this data. Thank you very much